# ViewEngineCollection alternative in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am migrating an Asp.Net MVC application to Asp.Net Core.

I came accross this line of code:

```
if (this.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(this.ControllerContext, viewPath, null).View != null)
{
    return this.View(viewPath);
}
```

I couldn't find any alternative way of performing ViewEngineCollection.FindView in asp.net core.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, thanks to [Henk Mollema](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823494/henk-mollema).

- Controller class

```cs
public class NewsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRazorViewEngine _razorViewEngine;
    private readonly IActionContextAccessor _actionContextAccessor;

    public NewsController(IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine, IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor)
    {
        _razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
        _actionContextAccessor = actionContextAccessor;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {   
        var gotView = _razorViewEngine.GetView(string.Empty, viewName, true);

        if (gotView.Success)   //gets true
        {
            return View(viewName);
        }
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

* startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

The same can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/alenjalex/Tryouts/tree/master/FindViewTryout).

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a `IRazorViewEngine` instance using dependency injection and call `FindView`. You have to pass in an `ActionContext` instance rather than a `ControllerContext` using this interface.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But, after trying this, I'm getting null for view, whereas when I try the same in asp.net with controllercontext, it works fine.

Comment: Can you update your answer and share what you've tried?

Comment: ```
var actionContext = new ActionContext(this.HttpContext, this.RouteData, this.ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor);
var view = razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewPath, true).View;
```

Comment: I tried `var view = _razorViewEngine.GetView("", viewPath, false);` and this worked for me

Comment: You could inject an `IActionContextAccessor` instance to get a hold of the current `ActionContext` instance. as well.

Comment: I tried injecting IActionContextAccessor into the contoller, but `view.Success` is still false, and `GetView()` works fine. The code is `var view = _razorViewEngine.FindView(_actionContextAccessor.ActionContext, "~/Views/News/Index.cshtml", true);`

Comment: You might have to register the `IActionContextAccessor` via `services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();`

Comment: I did do that. I have created a sample application for the same. You could probably give it a look @ https://github.com/alenjalex/Tryouts/blob/master/FindViewTryout/FindViewTryout/Controllers/NewsController.cs .