# .Net 5 alternative of ViewEngineCollection and FileSystemRazorViewEngine

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

How can i have alternative of this line below in **.net 5**
var engines = new **ViewEngineCollection** {new **FileSystemRazorViewEngine**(path)};

Comment: Do you have FileSystemRazorViewEngine class for .net 5  ?

Comment: The Microsoft doesn't contain any document about the `FileSystemRazorViewEngine`. Are you sure this class is in the asp.net package? If you are using a third party package, please check the related document and learn how to use it in the Asp.net core application. To the `ViewEngineCollection`, I suppose you want to use it to find the specified view, right? If that is the case, you could inject a `IRazorViewEngine` instance using dependency injection and call `FindView`, see [ViewEngineCollection alternative in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392049/).